# Creating an error number from stack trace

Tags: c#, java, php, android, cryptography

I'm coding in Java, on Android platform, but this isn't really a question for a specific programming language.

So ... If an error occurs in my program, i catch it within a try-catch statement and i would like to create an error number which I'll display to the user, giving him the opportunity to send me this error number.

The catch is that i would like to code the error in such a way that i get a small number (let's say a maximum of 5 digits) which i later on can decode and can find out exactly in which class, in which method and at which line number the error occured.

I'm guessing this is more of a cryptography issue, so has anyone got any ideas on how i should  go about doing this?

**EDIT**

I was thinking of giving a number to each file, each method and somehow use these values to create the error number, but i'm not sure how to calculate the actual error number so that it will work the other way around (decode it correctly).

Comment: You need to post code if you want help.  As a user the one thing I hate is "Error Codes" because they don't tell me anything, and makes me have to contact somebody, in order to solve a problem I likely can solve myself.

Comment: There isn't really code i can paste. After i catch the error inside the try-catch statement, the object returned is a vector, the StackTrace, from which i can get the method name, class, line number where the error occured. And from this point on, i need to use these to calcualte my error number. That's it.

Comment: Why wont you send yourself a stack trace and just ask user for permission to do so?

Comment: I realise this doesn't answer your question, but have you considered alternate approaches instead? For example giving the user an error message that would be a bit friendlier than a number, followed by a question of whether or not to submit the stack-trace to you (whether by email or via a web-service) directly. This could arguably be less complicated while actually providing a better user experience. Also you'd have the whole stack-trace rather than just a file and line number.

Comment: I've already implemented a way by which the user is asked if a message can be sent to my server with the necessary error information (stack trace). But at the same time i wanted to implement this, so i don't have to send a lot of error information back to the server.

Comment: I dont think this is more related to cryptography... a better approach as you suggested urself is that you will give a number to each file and so on... Better create an excel file or sumthing and later on as you recieve the error code can check it in that excel file and get result as you want.

Comment: @akhil Yes, but how am i supposed to create the error number from those values? If i just concatenate them, it will create a large number, too many characters. :) I wanted something small but with a lot of meaning behind it.

Comment: Thats what I tried to explain. Just create a sample of error code and there relevant explanation in an excel file and then can match them as you recieve the error code back. :)

Comment: For example 54321 : unauthorization 54 is for a specific class 32 is for some method within it 1 is for that error.

Comment: Yes. That's how i was thinking of doing it, but i wanted to take it a bit further, and also include inside the error code the other methods and classes up the StackTree. So i would find out that method 32 was called from method 5 which was called from method 10. :) That's why i said i would end up with a large error number. That's how i am going to do it eventually, if i can't figure out a way to do it. :)

Comment: I guess it depends on your program complexity as well. The higher it would be the lager number it would result as Error code.

Comment: I require some kind of hash function which only returns values under 1000 and the resulted code can be decoded. :) Wonder if something like that exists...

Comment: @AndreiBogdan that is a very weak hash function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will say it, this is a dreadful approach to debugging issues.  What you want to do is set up an enumeration that dictates the error codes + descriptions.  This would be similar to how Microsoft [does it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
ERROR_SUCCESS

    0 (0x0)

    The operation completed successfully
```

So on and so forth.  That way you can publish these things to your users, so you reduce the amount of emails / complaints that you get (to some degree).  Obfuscating the stack trace is going to be a nightmare for you, because it would almost seem that you are locking yourself into an unmanageable reporting system.  As your code base grows and/or you add more custom exceptions you will quickly break your design.  Also, this is a strong case of security through obscurity, wherein someone will potentially reverse engineer your process and start writing malicious code against you.

Better approach:

Get a JIRA account where the more technically savvy users can post the error plus description.  I believe FogBugz also has this functionality where you can upload these types of things and it allows the users to crop the images to focus on what you are looking for specifically.